# Microsoft.Search.Query, announcement list search scope returns no results

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-foundation, search-results

Created a search scope on a discussion list, am querying it, works fine.
Created a separate scope (folder related, same site) pointing to an announcement list.
I consistently get 0 results when running Search Queries.
At the same time, the sharepoint 2010, foundation search webpart is capable of returning results from the announcement list.
I use the same query for both.  Verified that the scope (after the crawl runs) contains files.

Can you help?
Heres my query in case its messed up.

```
var queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>" 
queryText += "<Query>" 
queryText += "<Range><Count>3000</Count></Range>"; 
queryText += "<Context>" 
queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>" 
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM SCOPE() WHERE (\"scope\" = '"+scope.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"') AND ( FREETEXT('"+term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"') OR FREETEXT(*,'\""+term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"\"') OR CONTAINS('FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, \""+term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"\")') OR CONTAINS('\""+term+"\"') )  AND (NOT CONTAINS(Path,'AllItems.aspx'))  AND (NOT CONTAINS(Path,'DispForm.aspx')) ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC"
queryText += "</QueryText>" 
queryText += "</Context>" 
queryText += "</Query>" 
queryText += "</QueryPacket>";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>" 
queryText += "<Query domain='QDomain'>" 
queryText += "<SupportedFormats><Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format></SupportedFormats>"; 
queryText += "<Range><Count>3000</Count></Range>"; 
queryText += "<Context>"
queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT'>" 
queryText += "SELECT Title, Rank, Size, Description, Write, Path FROM SCOPE() WHERE (\"scope\" = '"+scope.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"') AND ( FREETEXT('"+term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"') OR FREETEXT(*,'\""+term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"\"') OR CONTAINS('FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, \""+term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'')+"\")') OR CONTAINS('\""+term+"\"') )  AND (NOT CONTAINS(Path,'AllItems.aspx'))  AND (NOT CONTAINS(Path,'DispForm.aspx')) ORDER BY \"Rank\" DESC --"
queryText += "</QueryText>" 
queryText += "</Context>" 
queryText += "</Query>" 
queryText += "</QueryPacket>";
```

Note the items I added:

- domain='QDomain'

- urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document

- placed " --"  to the end of the query text immediately after the "ORDER BY." This is an "undocumented feature."